# Using Variables in Associative Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have data coming from two different pages using associative arrays, which is then used in another file.  I would like to use a variable instead of re-writing the function twice.

The first file fetches the data as

```
 $data['property_subcategory'];
```

The second file fetches the same data as

```
 $row['property_subcategory'];
```

Currently I am using the following conditions

```
if  ($currentseo == 'propertysearchresults') 
{
    $title = $data['property_subcategory'];
}

if  ($currentseo == 'propertyfavorite') 
{
    $title = $row['property_subcategory'];
}
```

Instead of this I would like to use something like the following

```
if  ($currentseo == 'propertysearchresults') 
{
    $variable = "$data";
}

if  ($currentseo == 'propertyfavorite') 
{
    $variable = "$row";
}

$title = $variable.['property_subcategory'];
```

I am getting the errror `Array to string conversion`

Comment: typo. remove the dot in `$title = $variable.['property_subcategory'];`

Comment: Eventually this helps you http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: To be honest with you - in this example I would stick with what you already had, the second version isn't as clear as the first.

Comment: please all see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with something like this idea, why not just set `$variable` equal to the array you need...

```
if  ($currentseo == 'propertysearchresults') 
{
    $variable = $data;
}

elseif  ($currentseo == 'propertyfavorite') 
{
    $variable = $row;
}

$title = $variable['property_subcategory'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that seems to be working based on comments given by Gordon and Doomenik

```
$variable= "data";

$title = "$".$variable['property_subcategory'];
```

However if the variable is to be used in an if/else condition then syntax changes like the following

```
if(${$variable}['property_subcategory'] == "Room")
```

Comment: since the functions are considerably longer than variable declaration (only a simple function was given here) my code will become considerably smaller and DRY.

Comment: This is horrible.

Comment: @Progrock I agree.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just copy or reference to a different variable name?

```
<?php

if($currentseo == 'propertyfavorite') 
    $data = &$row;
```